# Is it possible to make site_email an i18n variable?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, emails

We have multilingual site pointing to 2 domain according to site language.

> www.example.com (Swedish)
>
> www.other.com (English)

Now when some user post content from Swedish domain we want to send notification of content submission to user from info@example.com and if from English domain then from info@other.com

Is that possible ?

I have attempted like below in custom module whose weight is 1000:

```
function custom_overrides_init() {

  global $language;

  if($language->language == "sv"){
    variable_set('site_mail', "info@example.com");
  }else if($language->language == "en"){
    variable_set('site_mail', "info@other.com");
  }
}
```

When I see in maillog it shows correct from email addresse but its not working and use same email address which is set on site configuration.

**i18n_variable** also does not provide site_email as variable.

Please suggest !

Comment: Well, I don't have time to write the whole answer, so here is a comment to help you. The solution you are using (with hook_init) will not work in a production website, because if two visitors open a page at the same time there will be a problem. So, as you have a custom module, you can implement `hook_variable_info` or `hook_variable_info_alter` from **variable** module to add the translation option to `site_mail` variable.

Comment: @juankvillegas thanks! I have tired but it does not seems to work. That will be helpful if you can provide some demo code when you have time :)

Answer (score 1):

Your current solution is actually a very bad practice, as you will be rebuilding the variable cache on every page request, which is a big hit.

You can set the site_mail variable as translatable by installing the Variable module (http://dgo.to/variable), then implementing hook_variable_info() and declaring the site_mail variable.

```
function hook_variable()
{
  $variables['site_mail'] = array
  (
    'title' => t('Site Email'),
    'description' => t('The email addresses site mails are sent from'),
    'type' => 'string',
  );

  return $variables;
}
```

You then need to go to Admin -> Configuration -> Regional and Language -> Mutilingual settings -> Variables, and set site_mail as being translatable. You will then be able to visit the site information page and set a different value for the site mail in each language.

Comment: Now I can set separate email for separate languages. But still the default language site_mail is used to send emails. Please suggest if we need to do something else to make it use site email according to language ?

Comment: Just writing to confirm that site_email varibales is now multilingual and now I can add separate emails according to language but when it emails are sent out it does not use separate emails,  do we need to do some additional work ? please suggest ! + 1 for help so far thanks!

Comment: That is because it is *site* email, not *language* email. If you need a per language email then one could create another variable, not to translate the site_email. As I stated in my answer, if the module Domain Access would be used, together with the Domain Variable module, then a site_email variable per domain would exist. No need for custom coding.

Answer (score 0):

Two different questions are asked,

1. One question in the header:

> Is it possible to make site_email an i18n variable?

This is probably not what you want.

2. Another question in the text body:

> Now when some user post content from Swedish domain we want to send
>   notification of content submission to user from info@example.com and
>   if from English domain then from info@other.com
>
> Is that possible ?

Yes, it is possible and it is about *domains* as you state in this question (not *languages*).

The [Domain Variable](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_variable) module should be used together with the [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) module. These modules make the site_email as a variable per each domain. No custom coding needed.

You could then have these site emails:

- noreply@sweden.com (as sender for all languages on www.sweden.com)
- noreply@worldwide.com (as sender for all languages on www.worldwide.com)